# C++: How to carry over alignment and restric attributes to a template access function

Tags: c++, performance, memory-alignment, avx, avx2

I want to compute a general matrix matrix product

```
C = C + alpha*A*B
```

Now, the special situation in my context is that I know the number of columns of A (resp. the number of rows of B) at compile time. Therefore, I can hard-code this information, which naturally yields a significant performance boost.

Up to now, I have done this in Fortran, which works, but requires me to re-write the same code over and over again for all possible scenarios. Therefore, I would like to write *one* C++ version of this function, in which I pass the size information at compile time.

After a bit of trying, I finally arrived at the following solution

```
template<size_t sizeA2>
void matrixMatrixProduct( double* __restrict__ pC,
                          double const* __restrict__ pA,
                          double const* __restrict__ pB,
                          double alpha,
                          size_t sizeA1,
                          size_t sizeB2 )
{

  size_t outerLoopLimit = sizeA1;
  size_t innerLoopLimit = sizeB2;

  size_t sizeC2 = sizeB2;

  for ( size_t i = 0; i < outerLoopLimit; ++i )
  {
#pragma vector aligned
#pragma ivdep
    for ( size_t j = 0; j < innerLoopLimit; ++j )
    {
#pragma vector aligned
#pragma ivdep
      for ( size_t k = 0; k < sizeA2; ++k )
      {
        pC[i * sizeC2 + j] += alpha * pA[i * sizeA2 + k] * pB[k * sizeB2 + j];
      } // end of k-loop
    } // end of j-loop
  } // end of i-loop

}
```

Adding the restrict keyword and the two pragmas, I could convince the Intel Cpp compiler to vectorize the j-loop so that I got a maximum speed of about 19 GFlops on a single core of a Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz, which is in perfect agreement with the Fortran counter-part.

What I now want to do is extend the functionality, such that I can transpose the three matrices A, B, and C individually. To this end, my plan was to add a template access policy which flips the two indices if necessary. I extended the code as follows

```
template<size_t sizeA2,
         typename AccessOperatorA = NoTranspose,
         typename AccessOperatorB = NoTranspose,
         typename AccessOperatorC = NoTranspose >
void matrixMatrixProduct( double* __restrict__ pC,
                          double const* __restrict__ pA,
                          double const* __restrict__ pB,
                          double alpha,
                          size_t sizeA1,
                          size_t sizeB2 )
{

  size_t outerLoopLimit = sizeA1;
  size_t innerLoopLimit = sizeB2;

  size_t sizeC2 = sizeB2;

  for ( size_t i = 0; i < outerLoopLimit; ++i )
  {
#pragma vector aligned
#pragma ivdep
    for ( size_t j = 0; j < innerLoopLimit; ++j )
    {
#pragma vector aligned
#pragma ivdep
      for ( size_t k = 0; k < sizeA2; ++k )
      {
        AccessOperatorC::get( pC, sizeC2,  i, j ) += alpha * AccessOperatorA::get( pA, sizeA2, i, k ) * AccessOperatorB::get( pB, sizeB2, k, j );
      } // end of k-loop
    } // end of j-loop
  } // end of i-loop

}
```

with the NoTranspose access operator being defined as

```
struct NoTranspose
{
  template<typename DataType>
  static inline DataType& get( DataType* __restrict__ pointer,
                               size_t size2,
                               size_t i,
                               size_t j )
  {
    return pointer[i * size2 + j];
  }
};
```

In principle, this code compiles and give the correct answers, but at only 60% of the speed!

For my understanding, the problems seems to be that the alignment information is not carried over into the get function of the access template, although the get function is in-lined according the the perf. report. However, the icpc seems to decide to work on xmm registers only, which causes the performance penalty.

Therefore, my question is: how can get the compiler to correctly vetorize the extended code?

Any help is gratefully acknowledged.

For completeness, I add the complete MWE

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>

struct NoTranspose
{
  template<typename DataType>
  static inline DataType& get( DataType* __restrict__ pointer,
                               size_t size2,
                               size_t i,
                               size_t j )
  {
    return pointer[i * size2 + j];
  }
};

template<size_t sizeA2,
         typename AccessOperatorA = NoTranspose,
         typename AccessOperatorB = NoTranspose,
         typename AccessOperatorC = NoTranspose >
void matrixMatrixProduct( double* __restrict__ pC,
                          double const* __restrict__ pA,
                          double const* __restrict__ pB,
                          double alpha,
                          size_t sizeA1,
                          size_t sizeB2 )
{

  size_t outerLoopLimit = sizeA1;
  size_t innerLoopLimit = sizeB2;

  size_t sizeC2 = sizeB2;

  for ( size_t i = 0; i < outerLoopLimit; ++i )
  {
#pragma vector aligned
#pragma ivdep
    for ( size_t j = 0; j < innerLoopLimit; ++j )
    {
#pragma vector aligned
#pragma ivdep
      for ( size_t k = 0; k < sizeA2; ++k )
      {
        AccessOperatorC::get( pC, sizeC2,  i, j ) += alpha * AccessOperatorA::get( pA, sizeA2, i, k ) * AccessOperatorB::get( pB, sizeB2, k, j );
      } // end of k-loop
    } // end of j-loop
  } // end of i-loop

}

int main( void )
{

  std::vector<int> sizesA1 = { 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 125, 150, 175, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000 };

  printf( "%15s \t %15s \t%15s \t %15s\n", "sizeA1", "sizeA2", "Time [s]", "GFlops" );

  for ( const auto & sizeA1 : sizesA1 )
  {
    int numberOfIterations = 1e6;

    const int sizeA2 = 2;

    size_t sizeB2 = sizeA1;

    size_t sizeC1 = sizeA1;
    size_t sizeC2 = sizeB2;

    size_t lengthA = sizeA1 * sizeA2;
    size_t lengthB = sizeA2 * sizeB2;
    int lengthC = sizeC1 * sizeC2;

    std::vector<double> A1( lengthA, 1.234 );
    std::vector<double> B1( lengthB, 1.234 );
    std::vector<double> C1( lengthC, 1.234 );
    std::vector<double> A2( lengthA, 1.234 );
    std::vector<double> B2( lengthB, 1.234 );
    std::vector<double> C2( lengthC, 1.234 );

    double alpha = 1.234;

    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now( );
    for ( int i = 0; i < numberOfIterations; ++i )
    {
      double* pA;
      double* pB;
      double* pC;

      //Force cache reload
      if ( i % 2 )
      {
        pA = A1.data( );
        pB = B1.data( );
        pC = C1.data( );
      }
      else
      {
        pA = A2.data( );
        pB = B2.data( );
        pC = C2.data( );
      }

      matrixMatrixProduct<sizeA2>( pC, pA, pB, alpha, sizeA1, sizeB2 );

    }
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now( );
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed = end - start;

    double numberOfFlops = 1.0 * numberOfIterations * lengthC * ( 3 + 2 ); //two adds and three mult!
    double flops = (double) numberOfFlops / ( elapsed.count( ) );

    printf( "%15d \t %15d \t %15g \t %15e\n", sizeA1, sizeA2, elapsed.count( ), flops / ( 1.0e9 ) );

  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: From my experience, ICC is known to (sometimes) lose restrict and aliasing attributes across inlined functions. I have never found a reliable work-around that doesn't involve manually optimizing. Generally speaking, ICC's advanced optimizations (i.e. vectorization, loop transforms) don't play well with zero-overhead abstractions that are zero-overhead with other compilers. I have no idea why, but they seem to only optimize their compiler for straight-line code with only loops. Any time there's a function call involved (inlined or not), things start to fall apart.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply.
Is there an other compiler which supports this forwarding?

Comment: No idea. I don't rely on compilers for high-level optimizations because they are so bad and unreliable at it. I do know that MSVC does a pretty good job at preserving restrict/aliasing across inlined functions. But it's also terrible with advanced optimizations. GCC isn't able to utilize restrict as well as MSVC or ICC regardless of inlining. Supposedly they improved that for GCC6, but I haven't checked.

Comment: did you try clang?